# Firefox subpixel rendering on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, fonts, lcd

I was reading [this here blog entry](http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=983) and the page was driving my eyes NUTS.

Seems like it's the fault of Firefox on Ubuntu 12.04. It's had [this problem before, it seems](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/512615) but it should be fixed.

---

#### Firefox making my eyes bleed:

[image: firefox]

---

#### Chrome doing the Right Thing:

[image: chrome]

---

#### Firefox doing the Right Thing at work on the same monitor:

### [image: firefoxwork]

Is there anything I should be doing to make Firefox behave? Or is this strictly a bug?

Answer (score 3):

Firefox does not seem to read the GTK configuration, but it does read and honor your [`~/.fonts.conf`](http://freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html) which basically just contains the font configuration, including the sub-pixel order.

This is derived from [my own `.fonts.conf`](https://github.com/RobertZenz/BobbysDotFiles/blob/master/.fonts.conf) (which is derived from some blog post from somewhere around 2005...or so, no idea), what you most likely want to change is the `rgba` value (sub-pixel order) to match your LCD and maybe the `antialias` value.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
    <match target="font">
        <edit mode="assign" name="autohint">
            <bool>false</bool>
        </edit>
    </match>
    <match target="font">
        <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
            <const>rgb</const>
        </edit>
    </match>
    <match target="font">
        <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
            <bool>true</bool>
        </edit>
    </match>
    <match target="font">
        <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
            <const>hintfull</const>
        </edit>
    </match>
    <match target="font">
        <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
            <bool>true</bool>
        </edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_Configuration) also contains a lot of information about this.

Comment: OK… now neither of my systems has a `.fonts.conf`, but it looks OK at work on a similar system. I'll try this out later. Moar testing!

Comment: This needs to be marked as the answer. This (editing `~/.fonts.conf`) works, but editing `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`, or editing `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` (or the equivalent `fonts.conf.d` files) does not work. Looks like a firefox bug that no one else noticed, assuming no one would have different configurations. I use this file to disable antialiasing altogether, and my eyes thank me!

Comment: FYI: You can find out the current system-wide settings by running `gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings`. Then you can fill in those values in the XML posted above. You can find out the available options for the XML entries [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html).